# ISO 9797-1 MAC Algorithm 3 and Doc 9303-11

Tags: mac

I am trying to write a python script to access the IC in an eMRTD as per ICAO Doc 9303. Everything is going swimmingly until I come to the part where I need to calculate a MAC using ISO 9797-1 Algorithm 3 (padding mode 2).

In Appendix D-3, the MAC of E.IFD `72C29C2371CC9BDB65B779B8E8D37B29ECC154AA56A8799FAE2F498F76ED92F2` using K.MAC of `7962D9ECE03D1ACD4C76089DCE131543` is meant to return `5F1448EEA8AD90A7`.

However, when I calculate the MAC, it returns `AAE3F35132ED3465`. This is the return when I run through the steps step-by-step using pyDes (ECB mode and manually xoring as appropriate) and when I use the code as written [here](https://bono02.wordpress.com/2015/08/16/des-mac-iso-9797-alg-3-m1-m2-m-is-padding-method/).

I am clearly missing something - would love any help!

Comment: A lot of passports also allow AES encryption / MAC by now. In that case you can simply use AES-CMAC, which is a lot more common. This ISO 9797-1 Algorithm 3 MAC is also known as Retail MAC (as it was defined by the financial industry) or ISO 7816-4 MAC (which is a bad name, as it is only used, not defined in that standard).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to calculate a MAC using ISO 9797-1 Algorithm 3 (padding mode 2)

and the context makes references to 3DES (as confirmed by the 8-byte width of the result without mention of truncation, and the fact that all bytes of the test key `7962D9ECE03D1ACD4C76089DCE131543` have odd parity).

ISO/IEC 9797-1:2011 (revising the 1999 edition) specifies MAC algorithms based on an iterated block cipher with CBC chaining, along the general structure of [CBC-MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CBC-MAC). With Algorithm 3, the structure is:

[image: ISO/IEC 9797-1 Algorithm 3]

The standard has a Padding Method 2 (not "padding mode 2") where a single 1 bit is appended to the input, then just enough 0 bits (possibly none) to reach a multiple of the block width. Since the input is 32-byte, there are four 8-byte blocks and a last padding block *mx* of `8000000000000000`.

We get `F97B82EC7727D582` after the fourth encryption, then `797B82EC7727D582` after XOR of the padding block, then `5F1448EEA8AD90A7`as the result.

Caution: there is an attack on this MAC Algorithm 3 recovering the key with the order of $2^{32}$ MAC queries of short messages to find a collision, followed by in the order of $2^{57}$ offline DES operations to recover K1, then K2.